# Audio wav file not working anymore in java

Tags: java, audio, playback

Why is the following wav audio file not playing in java, the strange thing, is that it worked, but when I closed Netbean and reopened the project, it would not play anymore.

If i try `URL url = new URL("http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav");` it works?!?!

Code

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Audio/police.wav");
// URL url = new URL("http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav");
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(ais);
```

The error is

```
Sep 05, 2013 9:40:40 PM javafxapplication4.JavaFXApplication4$1 run
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence(StandardMidiFileReader.java:205)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence(MidiSystem.java:838)
    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(SoftMidiAudioFileReader.java:174)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1146)
    at javafxapplication4.JavaFXApplication4$1.run(JavaFXApplication4.java:268)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

my wav file is located here

[image]

Comment: what are the symptoms you're experiencing? error, exception, ...

Comment: I have edited the post with the errors

Comment: I don't quite understand the data shown in the image.  But from the little I understand, it seems that the wav is actually located at `"/javafxapplication4/Audio/police.wav"`.  Try that exact string (with leading `/`).

Answer (score 0):

You can build AudioInputStream this way:

```
InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("Audio/police.wav");
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is);
```

Don't forget to check if the InputStream is null. It will give you more control to investigate if something goes wrong. This snippet assumes there is a resource Audio/police.wav available in your classpath

Comment: Thanks, but still  the same. look at the image i uploaded, this is the location of the wav file. the strange thing, is that this code worked all day yesterday on 2 computers

Comment: according to your picture, your ressource location is: javafxapplication4/Audio/police.wav

(the package is part of the location when you use this way of loading resources)

Comment: That is a folder, but showing differently in the project tree. I modified the location as per your suggestion but still the same, not working!!!

Comment: packages are usually folders, certainly in common IDE such as netbeans. The picture you provide indicates the file as being part of one of the packages. for more details about how classloaders are used to load system resources see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)